# MSSQL - Backup Database has wrong size

Tags: linux, bash, backup, database, sql-server

I have a database backup (.bak) with 10GB size which I import in my MSSQL-Database via:

```sql
USE [master]
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [<dbname>] FROM  DISK = N'$BAKFILEWITHPATH' WITH FILE = 1, MOVE N'$LOGICNAME' TO N'/var/opt/mssql/data/$BAKFILENOEXT.mdf',  MOVE N'$LOGFILE' TO N'/var/opt/mssql/data/$BAKFILELOG.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
GO
```

(there are several variables contained because this query is created with a bash script.)
That works. Then I drop the BLOB column which is 90% of the backup size. (~9GB)

```sql
USE [$BAKFILENOEXT]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BLOB] DROP COLUMN [Blob]
GO
```

Then I backup my imported database without the Blob row again to a .bak file. The Backup should now just be 1GB big right?

```sql
BACKUP DATABASE [$BAKFILENOEXT] TO  DISK = N'$_mountpoint/$BAKFILE' WITH FORMAT, INIT,  MEDIADESCRIPTION = N'$blobstatus',  MEDIANAME = N'$blobstatus',  NAME = N'complete backup without blob column', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

But the BAK file is again 10GB big. How can that be? It has no BLOB Row anymore, it has to be 1GB. But It's 10GB. How?

Sitenotes:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
SQL: MSSQL Server 2017
and I start the sql-scripts with the tool SQLCMD

Comment: Did you truncate the transaction log and/or shrink the database and log files?

Comment: No I didn't, should I? I Just executet these 3 sql scripts and whondered why the backup has still the original size.